# Launching exe from server share

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

We have a password utility sitting on a server share. I want to launch it from a button within PowerShell GUI. The exe isn't launching. I think I have the right code though.

```
Function pwd()
{
    Invoke-Item "\\servershare\pwd\passwordutility.exe"
}
```

Comment: What problem are you running into? What message are you seeing in PowerShell?

Comment: I don't receive any message. When I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried invoking the command outside a UI and seen what happens?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean it says error loading config file. Now the config file is in the folder. I tried mapping a drive to the folder and launching from there but same thing happens. But I'm able to launch it normally if I browse out the folder and double click the exe

Answer (score 0):

> it says error loading config file. Now the config file is in the folder.

Your problem is trying to use `Invoke-Item` from your current directory.  You really should use `Start-Process` when launching executables:

```
function pwd() {
    $share = '\\servershare\pwd'
    Start-Process -FilePath "$share\passwordutility.exe" -WorkingDirectory $share
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that and It doesn't launch the exe. Actually doesn't do anything. What did work was the following $btn3.Add_Click({Start-Process -filepath "\\share\pwd\passwordutility.exe" -WorkingDirectory "\\share\pwd\" })

Answer (score -1):

Thank you to @TheIncorrigible1 for his help I was able to get it working but just adding this line to a button click

```
$btn3.Add_Click({Start-Process -filepath "\\sharename\pwd\passwordutility.exe" -WorkingDirectory "\\sharename\pwd\" })
```